# Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer

Tags: sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

I am using the DataMapper gem with Sinatra and followed the tutorial here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-datamapper/

I am connecting to the database and migrating as such:

```
DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/ex2.db"
DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

My data model:

```
class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id       , Serial
    property :username , String
    property :email    , String
end
```

I am executing using this command:

```
rackup config.ru
```

However, when I get to this line:

```
User.create username: "JoeSchmo", email: "joe@schmo.com"
```

I receive the error:

```
Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are there any other Rack middlewares setup? Can you add the `require` statements from your app? And are your gems up-to-date? Please include versions if possible.

Comment: I was getting this same error when I dealt with DataMapper objects that had subclasses. Are you doing any subclassing or inheritance?

Comment: any answers to this yet? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and it was caused by a DataMapper error. Try `begin; User.create(username: "foo", email: "abc@def.com"); rescue => e; return e.inspect; end` and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the SQLite DB - there seems to be a bug in data_mapper with changing the data structure and using old data. For me the bug went away after deleting the db and setting up a new one.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ruby are you on because if you are on less than 1.9 you have to use the `=>` hash constructor not `:` and move the colon to the beginning because it is a symbol.

```
User.create :username => "JoeSchmo", :email => "joe@schmo.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Sinatra and datamapper. Creating my records with "new" keyword rather than "create" and then adding attributes one by one worked for me. Hope you find it useful.